# "this" context output not able to understand

Tags: javascript

I am facing difficulty understanding the below code.

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var obj = {
    a: 2,
    foo: foo
};

var a = 4;

obj.foo();
setTimeout( obj.foo, 100 );
setTimeout( obj.foo.bind(obj), 100 );
```

Its output comes as 2, 4, 2 which I am not able to understand.

Comment: are you using this is the exact code snippet? that should do 2 undefined 2

Comment: Your question shows that you lack the understanding of how `setTimeout()` works. Please read this [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem)

Comment: Thanks @Dummy for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case,

```
obj.foo();
```

Where the `this` inside of `foo` will point `obj` since you have assigned the function as a property of that particular object.

The second case,

```
setTimeout( obj.foo, 100 );
```

In setTimeout, the passed function will be `eval`uated in the window's context. So here `var a = 4;` was executed in window's context and became the property of window. when accessing `this` inside the function `foo`, that would point to `window` at this particular situation.

The third case,

```
setTimeout( obj.foo.bind(obj), 100 );
```

You just bound the `obj` as `this` to the function `foo`. And even though the function evaluated in window's context, the bound `this` value won't be changed. That is the rule behind `bind` function. So the `this` won't be changed from `obj` to `window` here.

Answer (score 2):

`this` keyword behaves a little differently in difference context.

### Global context

In the global execution context (outside of any function), this refers to the global object, whether in strict mode or not.

### Function context

Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.

#### Simple call

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this)
}
```

In non-strict mode, `this` will default to the global object

In strict mode, `this` will default to undefined

#### `call` or `apply`

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this)
}
var o = {'name': 'test object'};
foo.call(o) // log object `o`
```

`this` can be bound to a particular object in the call using the call or apply methods.

#### `bind`

`bind` method return a function that use specific object by `bind` as `this` object in the function.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this)
}
var o = {'name': 'test object'};
bar = foo.bind(o)
bar() // log object `o`
```

Refer to this link for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

### Explain

in this case `obj.foo();` `this` of function `foo` is `obj`, so `this.a` refer to `obj.a`

in this case `setTimeout( obj.foo, 100 );` `obj.too` is a reference to the function `foo`. `setTimeout` will execute it in global context.

in this case  `setTimeout( obj.foo.bind(obj), 100 );`, `obj.foo.bind(obj)` return a reference to a function which bind `this` with `obj`. `setTimeout` will execute it in context of `obj`

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how `this` behaves. It's called function execution context and you can read more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

In the first case, the function is called in the context of the object `obj`, since property accessor `.` is used (`obj.foo`) and hence `this` points to `obj`.

In the second case, you pass the standalone function to `setTimeout` and it will be called in the global context, `this` pointing to window. 
`obj.foo()` is not the same as `var f = obj.foo; f()`

In the third case, you bound the context of a function call to `obj`, and `this` points to obj again. Read more about `bind` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an `alert(this);` inside foo() method to understand the context.

`obj.foo();` => runs in object context and hence result will be value of `a` inside `obj` => 2

`setTimeout( obj.foo, 100 );` => runs in window context and `var a = 4` being in the window context, `this.a` gives 4 (`this` here is `window`)

and the last line will again have the object context => 2

Comment: absolutely sure, that you will see [object Object] in all 3 cases.

Comment: @degr - please check out this fiddle -https://jsfiddle.net/qcz5p69s/ . the second alert will show `[object Window]`

Comment: @degr - please let me know if you are not seeing that. Thank you